# Unit Tests for C++ with VS2015 to test Vector Population

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am trying to write Unit Test for a C++ routine, using Visual Studio 2015 and it's test framework. I have followed a tutorial and set up the test project, but the first test I am running keeps failing.

My Routine I want to test:

```
vector< vector<int> > history;
vector<int> values;

void populateArray(int input, int time) {
    values.push_back(time);
    values.push_back(input);
    if (history.size() > 0) {
        values.push_back(values[0] - history.back()[0]);
        values.push_back(values[1] - history.back()[1]);
        values.push_back(values[3] / values[2]);
    }

    history.push_back(values);

};
```

My Test Code:

```
TEST_CLASS(MyTests)
{
public:
    TEST_METHOD(Array_Populates)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 2) {
            populateArray(dummyData[i][0], dummyData[i][1]);
            Assert::AreEqual(history[i][0], dummyData[i][1]);
            i++;
        }
        int j = 0;
        while (j < history.size()) {
            j++;
        } 
    }

    int const MyTests::dummyData[15][2] = {
        { 95, 86400 },
        { 77, 172800 },
        { 76, 259200 },
        { 75, 345600 },
        { 65, 432000 },
        { 65, 518400 },
        { 65, 604800 },
        { 60, 691200 },
        { 52, 777600 },
        { 51, 864000 },
        { 50, 950400 },
        { 40, 1036800 },
        { 40, 1123200 },
        { 40, 1209600 },
        { 35, 1296000 }
    };
};
```

I am trying to populate the vector row by row with a line of the Dummy Array. The after that is done, I would like to check that every line is correct. However, if I run the test, where the loop goes more than once, it fails, saying that the expected value was 95, but actual value was 77. I am not sure if this is an error with the vector code, but I can't see one. Or if it is with my understanding of the Unit Test code.

Thanks For Your Help.

Comment: debug it so you'll know

Comment: Is `values` a global variable? You never create it in your sample code yet you keep calling push_back on it. So I reckon `histroy.back()[0]` is always the first value you put in (86400 if I am not mistaken).

Comment: @rozina Sorry, updated. Yes, that was something I put in for another test to make sure I wasn't going mad. With the above edited code however, I get the same result.

Comment: You never reset `values` so `histroy[i][0] == 86400` for any `i`

Comment: @rozina Thank you very much. That's got it!